# Get information about new instances spawned by auto scaling using CLI

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, autoscaling, aws-cli

I am working on creating a monitor dashboard for monitoring status of ec2 instances.
I am searching for a method to get information (especially instances ID) of newly spawned instances using auto scaling.
Can anyone point me in the right direction. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get instance id by using combination of following commands

```
aws elb describe-load-balancers --load-balancer-name "LoadBalanceID" --region "region" --output text | grep INSTANCES
```

Answer (score 1):

If you know your instance type then you can use [describe-instances](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ec2/describe-instances.html) command to get details about instances and use query command to get the details what you need (in your case Instance-id)

```
aws ec2 describe-instances --filters "Name=instance-type,Values=t1.micro" --query 'Reservations[*].{InstanceId:Instances[0].InstanceId}'

## Enter your instance type in the 'Values' field of '--filters' command
```

Comment: I am actually searching to get information about all the instance type

Answer (score 0):

Using the AWS CLI you can get a list of scaling activities for an auto scaling group.

```
aws autoscaling describe-scaling-activities --auto-scaling-group-name my-group-name
```

See [AWS CLI](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/autoscaling/describe-scaling-activities.html)

This is the newer Python CLI, so you would need to install that if you have not already done so. It will return a JSON block with all of the scale up and down activities in the group, including the reason an the date and time.